# R shiny problem calling my function with a button

Tags: r, shiny

I have defined a function in the server as " RunPlot <- function(tickers, sharesVec, FromDate, ToDate)". The function should return a single numerical value. I want to output this value by clicking on the button "Go", but when I click on the button, nothing happens. Also, I have tried calling this function in a separate script and everything worked so there is no error inside the function. Here is my code:

UI

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel("test"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            actionButton("Go", "Go!")
        ),

        mainPanel(
            textOutput("TEST")
        )
    )
))
```

Server

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)                            
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    RunPlot <- function(tickers, sharesVec, FromDate, ToDate){
        
        PortfolioPrices <- NULL 
        for (i in tickers){
            PortfolioPrices <- cbind(PortfolioPrices, 
                                     getSymbols.yahoo(i, from = FromDate, to = ToDate,             
                                                      auto.assign = F)[,6])  
        }  
        
        TempValue <- PortfolioPrices[1,]
        MarketValue <- sharesVec*TempValue
        Weights <- MarketValue/sum(MarketValue) #Now have Weights AND Tickers vectors
        
        #C) Compute Portfolio Returns
        for (j in 1:ncol(PortfolioPrices)){          #Data cleaning                                                      
            for (i in 1:nrow(PortfolioPrices)){
                if (is.na(PortfolioPrices[i,j]) == TRUE){
                    PortfolioPrices[i,j] <- PortfolioPrices[i-1,j]
                }
            }
        }
        
        Rf <- getQuote("^TNX", src = "yahoo")[1,2]/100
        AssetsReturns <- na.omit(ROC(PortfolioPrices, type = "discrete"))                                  
        PortfolioReturns <- Return.portfolio(AssetsReturns, weights = Weights)                             
        PortfolioAnnualizedReturns <- table.AnnualizedReturns(PortfolioReturns, Rf = Rf/252)                            
        colnames(PortfolioAnnualizedReturns) <- "Portfolio"
        
        #D) Compute Benchmark Returns
        SP500 <- getSymbols.yahoo("SPY", from = FromDate, to = ToDate, auto.assign = F)[,6]       
        SP500Returns <- na.omit(ROC(SP500, type = "discrete"))                                             
        SP500AnnualizedReturns <- table.AnnualizedReturns(SP500Returns, Rf = Rf/252)  
        colnames(SP500AnnualizedReturns) <- "S&P500"
        
        SPTSX <- getSymbols.yahoo("XIC.TO", from = FromDate, to = ToDate, auto.assign = F)[,6]   
        SPTSXReturns <- na.omit(ROC(SPTSX, type = "discrete"))                                             
        SPTSXAnnualizedReturns <- table.AnnualizedReturns(SPTSXReturns, Rf = Rf/252) 
        colnames(SPTSXAnnualizedReturns) <- "S&P/TSX"
        
        MSCIIMI <- getSymbols.yahoo("XEF.TO", from = FromDate, to = ToDate, auto.assign = F)[,6]   
        MSCIIMIReturns <- na.omit(ROC(MSCIIMI, type = "discrete"))                                             
        MSCIIMIAnnualizedReturns <- table.AnnualizedReturns(MSCIIMIReturns, Rf = Rf/252) 
        colnames(MSCIIMIAnnualizedReturns) <- "MSCI EAFE IMI"
        
        MSCIEME <- getSymbols.yahoo("XEC.TO", from = FromDate, to = ToDate, auto.assign = F)[,6]   
        MSCIEMEReturns <- na.omit(ROC(MSCIEME, type = "discrete"))                                             
        MSCIEMEAnnualizedReturns <- table.AnnualizedReturns(MSCIEMEReturns, Rf = Rf/252) 
        colnames(MSCIEMEAnnualizedReturns) <- "MSCI Emerging Markets"
        
        #E) Format Data
        PortfolioCumReturns <- fortify.zoo(PortfolioReturns+1)                                             
        SP500CumReturns <- fortify.zoo(SP500Returns+1)
        SPTSXCumReturns <- fortify.zoo(SPTSXReturns+1)
        MSCIIMICumReturns <- fortify.zoo(MSCIIMIReturns+1)
        MSCIEMECumReturns <- fortify.zoo(MSCIEMEReturns+1)
        
        for (j in 2:nrow(PortfolioCumReturns)){                                                            
            PortfolioCumReturns[j,2] <- PortfolioCumReturns[j-1,2]*PortfolioCumReturns[j,2]
        }
        for (j in 2:nrow(SP500CumReturns)){
            SP500CumReturns[j,2] <- SP500CumReturns[j-1,2]*SP500CumReturns[j,2]
        }
        for (j in 2:nrow(SPTSXCumReturns)){
            SPTSXCumReturns[j,2] <- SPTSXCumReturns[j-1,2]*SPTSXCumReturns[j,2]
        }
        for (j in 2:nrow(MSCIIMICumReturns)){
            MSCIIMICumReturns[j,2] <- MSCIIMICumReturns[j-1,2]*MSCIIMICumReturns[j,2]
        }
        for (j in 2:nrow(MSCIEMECumReturns)){
            MSCIEMECumReturns[j,2] <- MSCIEMECumReturns[j-1,2]*MSCIEMECumReturns[j,2]
        }
        
        PortfolioCumReturns <- PortfolioCumReturns - 1                                                      
        SP500CumReturns <- SP500CumReturns - 1
        SPTSXCumReturns <- SPTSXCumReturns - 1
        MSCIIMICumReturns <- MSCIIMICumReturns - 1
        MSCIEMECumReturns <- MSCIEMECumReturns - 1
        
        ### Results ###
        
        ReturnsTABLE <- cbind(PortfolioAnnualizedReturns,SP500AnnualizedReturns,SPTSXAnnualizedReturns,MSCIIMIAnnualizedReturns,MSCIEMEAnnualizedReturns)
        
        Benchmark <- getSymbols.yahoo("^GSPC", from = FromDate, to = ToDate, auto.assign = F)[,6]   
        BenchmarkReturns <- na.omit(ROC(Benchmark, type = "discrete"))  
        BETA <- CAPM.beta(PortfolioReturns, BenchmarkReturns, Rf/252)
        ALPHA <- CAPM.jensenAlpha(PortfolioReturns, BenchmarkReturns, Rf/252)
        
        return(BETA)   
        
    }


observeEvent(input$Go, {
    BETA <- RunPlot("MSFT",5,as.Date("2019-12-31"),as.Date("2020-12-31"))
})
output$TEST <- renderText({
    paste(BETA)
})
    
})
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object `BETA` is only available inside the observer.  One way to make it available outside is to create a `reactiveValues` object as shown below.

```
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$Go, {
    rv$BETA <- RunPlot("MSFT",5,as.Date("2019-12-31"),as.Date("2020-12-31"))
  })
  output$TEST <- renderText({
    paste(rv$BETA)
  })
```

[image: output]

**EDIT:**

with user input dates from `dateRangeInput` on the `ui` side

```
textInput("symb", "Symbol", value="MSFT"),
dateRangeInput("dates","Date range",start = "2019-01-01",end = as.character(Sys.Date())),
```

server side call will be

```
rv$BETA <- RunPlot(req(input$symb),5,input$dates[1],input$dates[2])
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks it worked! Also, if you don't mind, I am actually trying to call the function using user inputs (instead of the fixed "as.Date("2019-12-31")"). This is how I have defined it in the server: `FromDate <-reactive({as.Date(paste0(as.numeric(input$DateFrom)-1,"-12-31"))})` where the input$DateFrom is a YEAR. I get the error: "do not know how to convert 'x' to class “Date”". Any idea @YBS ? Everything worked in a script without the "reactive" at the beginning.

Comment: Everything worked well thank you! I have posted a new related question (hopefully my last) here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66716153/r-shiny-trouble-with-renderplot) if you have time to give it a look @YBS